# PNG Image Become transparent when increase distance of camera in WPF code

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit, wpf-4.0

I had set png Image as Brush background of Rectangle and set rectangle to Vieport3D group.

But when i am trying to increase distance of camera Image Become Transparent. But this problem face in XP only with windows7 it works fine

```
PointCollection pc = new PointCollection();
        Uri url = new Uri(@"Model/somefile.png", UriKind.Relative);

        BitmapImage bmpimg = new BitmapImage();
        bmpimg.BeginInit();
        bmpimg.UriSource = url;
        bmpimg.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bmpimg.EndInit();


        ImageBrush BrushView = new ImageBrush(bmpimg);
        BrushView.TileMode = TileMode.Tile;
        BrushView.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
        Material MaterialView = new DiffuseMaterial(BrushView);
        MeshGeometry3D mesh_light = new MeshGeometry3D();

        double Zdeep = -40;
        double x = -110;
        double y = -45;
        double xEnd = 110;
        double yEnd = 90;


        // Draw rectangle and set Image to Mash geometry 
        //pc.makeRectangle(mesh_light, new Point3D(x, y, Zdeep), new Point3D(x + xEnd, y, Zdeep), new Point3D(x + xEnd, yEnd, Zdeep), new Point3D(x, yEnd, Zdeep), new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 1), new Point(1, 1), new Point(1, 0));
        pc.makeRectangle(mesh_light, new Point3D(x, yEnd, Zdeep), new Point3D(x, y, Zdeep), new Point3D(xEnd, y, Zdeep), new Point3D( xEnd, yEnd, Zdeep), new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 1), new Point(1, 1), new Point(1, 0));
        GeometryModel3D LightGeometry = new GeometryModel3D(mesh_light, MaterialView);
        group.Children.Add(LightGeometry);
```

here when i set  double Zdeep = 0; it look fine but if i use  double Zdeep = -40; this value then image become transparent